# Rails 3.1: Validation fails when saving new objects with has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

```
# article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :article_categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :article_categories

  validates :title, :description, :body, presence: true
  validates :categories, presence: true
  validates_associated :categories
end

#articles_controller.rb
def create
    @article = Article.new(params[:article])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @article, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

I have an Article model related to one or more Categories. I want to make sure that an article is assigned to a category each time the record is saved. On update, this works fine, but on create, I get an `unprocessable entity` because the `ArticleCategory` association can't be created because it needs the `id` of the article. But, the `id` isn't set until the `Article` is saved. But I can't save invalid models. You get the idea. How can I `create` objects without sacrificing my validations?

**Edit:** I fixed the validation line. This is cleaned up to remove some other stuff so I accidentally deleted the `presence: true`

Comment: I'm surprised you aren't getting an `ArgumentError` here. You need to specify a validation on `validates :categories` and your first `validates` line looks off too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of validating that an article has many categories, can you try validate the presence of the join table, like:

```
# article.rb
validates :article_categories, presence: true
```

Comment: But, ArticleCategory can't be saved without an article_id to point the thing to. That's the problem. On create, the `id` doesn't exist. On update (of an existing article I created by hand in `rails console`) it works great.

Comment: oh right, yes remove the validation for the article_id and to ensure that you don't get a NULL value for the article_id set a null constraint on the DB column.

Comment: are you validating `article_id` or `article` on the article category model? It might pass validation if you validate the association `article` instead of the `article_id` column.

Comment: The way I see it, the validation is on the article's side. I want to validate that the article is created with category(ies) selected. If there aren't `category_ids` specified the article shouldn't be saved either on create or update. But the association table `article_categories` needs to have both the `article_id` and the `category_id` in order to have a valid association. But `article.id` doesn't exist until the article has been saved…

Comment: It doesn't matter if the article.id is not present. If you validate `article` instead, so validate the getter method returns the association; it should do what you want. Article should be present on an ArticleCategory when you build it or save through nested_attributes_for.

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at the Rails Guides for the proper format here:

```
has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
```

[From here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)! I think you'll find your declarations in the improper format.

Comment: he's using ruby 1.9 style hashes, the syntax looks fine.